# Не получается запустить spring boot проект

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Никак не получается запустить spring boot проект. Свой код не дописывал нигде, всё по умолчанию с spring initializr. Всё что сделал, это pom.xml сделал мавеном. Вот мавен код:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image: Вот фото]

Перепробовал уже многое: кэш очищал, jdk переустанавливал, в конфиге менял. Вот конфиг (здесь я пробовал разные методы, это просто последний)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот я так же делал как на видео до 7 минуты, на 7 минуте у нее такая же ситуация, но она обрезала момент как исправляла эти ошибки. Вот видео: https://youtu.be/SQCewtrHPN4

Буду очень благодарен за решение.

Comment: Она проимпортировала проект как Maven Project и Идея построила правильный classpath, так что ничего она не обрезала.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, а как построить правильный classpath?

Comment: Этим должен заниматься Мавен. Идея его вызывает, когда импортирует проект. Не знаю, почему Идея у тебя не отработала. Интернет у тебя включен? Мавен всё же из интернета качает.

Comment: попробуй нажми на pom.xml 2й кнопкой мышки, maven->Reload project